# Is there a proof that runST is indeed pure?

Tags: haskell, semantics, proof, st-monad

The [ST monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-ST.html), originally devised by [Launchbury and Peyton Jones](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=178243.178246), allows Haskell programmers to write imperative code (with mutable variables, arrays, etc.) while obtaining a pure interface to that code.

More concretely, the polymorphic type of the [entry point function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-ST.html#v:runST)

```
runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
```

ensures that all side-effects of the `ST` computation is contained, and the resulting value is pure.

Has this ever been rigorously (or even formally) proven?

Comment: Rigorously proven – in what framework? _All_ types in Haskell contain only pure values, so proving this property is a bit like proving that a given natural number, defined in some way, is not negative.

Comment: This paper claims that it hasn't: `none of the papers
we came across in our literature study actually establishes the safety
of the ST monad in Haskell` http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~pbuiras/publications/KeyMonadHaskell2016.pdf

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I believe the issue is proving that an STRef can never escape from its runST prison.

Comment: @PaulJohnson That's delicate indeed. Since it _can_ escape, if wrapped in an existential or `Dynamic`. But in such case, even if it can be fed to `readSTRef, writeSTRef`, the resulting action is still existentially quantified, hence can not be passed to `runST`. Proving all of this formally apparently is not trivial.

Comment: Great reference, @danidiaz; that probably constitutes a valid answer.

Comment: I noticed that I did not clarify what I mean with “pure”, and now I notice that there does not seem to exist a standard formal definition of pureness, let alone a proof that Haskell or Core is pure… What a rabbit hole.

Comment: Amr Sabry argues in [What is a Purely Functional Language](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0956796897002943), that *lazy* `ST` isn't pure according to the definition of purity Sabry provides. To answer your question, the first thing you'd need to do is actually define "pure". Sabry provides arguments why the typical "definitions" are, perhaps, inadequate and proposes an alternative.

Comment: @DerekElkins, theoretical concerns aside, lazy ST had a major concurrency bug (fixed in 8.2) that made it really impure in multi-threaded programs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It just so happens that Amin Timany et al. have published a paper at POPL2018 about exactly this topic, titled

> Amin Timany, Léo Stefanesco, Morten Krogh-Jespersen, and Lars Birkedal:
> **A Logical Relation for Monadic Encapsulation of State**
> Proving contextual equivalences in the presence of runST

https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3158152

---

Four years later, there is another paper on this, now proving that adding ST preserves *all* equational properties of the language (in a simply typed call-by-value language):

> Koen Jacobs, Dominique Devriese, Amin Timany:
> **Purity of an ST monad: full abstraction by semantically typed back-translation**

https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3527326

Comment: Oh ok. There goes another research project idea down the has-been-done-before drain…

Comment: The link is a 404 now. Where can I find an updated link?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  The paper has been published at POPL2018. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 15):

Here is an [Agda formalization](http://code.haskell.org/~Saizan/ST/ST.agda) by Andrea Vezzosi, which proves that `runST` is safe and total for an `ST` monad with readable/writable refs. It relies on postulated parametricity, i. e. the truth of the free theorems for the involved definitions, which is as expected, since parametricity is precisely the reason why the `forall s.` trick works.

However, the proof assumes that we can't put values inside an `STRef s` with types which themselves depend on `ST s`. In Haskell we can use such dependency to get looping without recursion:

```
loop :: ()
loop = runST $ do
  x <- newSTRef (pure ())
  writeSTRef x $ do
    y <- readSTRef x
    y
  y <- readSTRef x
  y
```

Probably this version of the ST monad is still safe, just does not have provably total `writeSTRef` and `readSTRef`.

Comment: So one would have to prove parametricity for Haskell or Core, which, as far as I know, also has not been done yet.

Comment: Also, without commentary, the Agda formalization is not easy for me to follow, I must admit.

Comment: `do y <- readSTRef x; y` is the same as `join (readSTRef x)`, right?

Comment: I did a [much simpler](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/07310be00e2a1bb9e94d7c8dbd1dced6) Agda formalization of  ST, if you're interested. It also computes properly, without any unsafe shenanigans.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, how does your theorem relate to the ones proven in the two papers in the other answer?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I only do total ST where ST actions can't be stored in STRefs. The papers include unrestricted (non-total) ST. Probably my formalization can be extended to a universe hierarchy where we can store "small" ST actions in "large" STRefs.

Comment: I’d love to see a longer paper/blog post/talk about this :-) The size difference to, say, https://github.com/scaup/sem_backs_st/tree/e14aa7f421de94df5c1369d2b4b44d8644243cec is enormous